# Image links in IE 11

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, anchor

I haven't tested this on all versions of IE but I have a problem that when I go to this site: http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/manufactured/ and click on one of the image links in the navigation menu (Home, Manufacted Homes, or Real Estate) it just opens the image of the button in the same window. It doesn't do this in Chrome or Firefox (it goes to the link as it should). Has anyone seen this before or does anyone know a solution?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="textwidget">
  <a href="http://yourwhiteknight.com/">
    <img src="http://yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/home.button.png" class="icon">
  </a>
  <a href="http://yourwhiteknight.com/manufactured/">
    <img width="233" height="38" src="http://yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/m.homes-tab.png" class="homes">
  </a>
  <a href="http://realestate.yourwhiteknight.com">
    <img src="http://yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/real-estate-tab.png" class="real">
  </a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

UPDATE:

I did just notice that when I inspect the element in IE it shows the code for an image as this:

```
<img width="233" height="38" class="homes" src="http://yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/m.homes-tab.png"></img>
```

I tried to add a slash at the end of the image code to no avail ()

Funny thing is that if you go to our other site that is a mirror of this one the buttons work: http://realestate.yourwhiteknight.com/ even though the code on the back end is the exact same.

Comment: As soon as I disable JavaScript in my IE, the problem disappears. So go check what kind of event handlers are getting attached to those images or the links around them – probably some kind of lightbox script or something of that sort, that wants to display linked images in a fancy way, and if it doesn’t find a “large” version of the image falls back to just redirecting to the address in the `src` attribute of the image element.

Comment: also, check the console for errors

Comment: I checked the Console and Debugger in IE 11 and didn't find any errors. Not sure what to look for here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by a plugin called: Google Analytics Suite. I just deactivated it and it started working. Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_self"` to the links and it works as a workaround. There is probably some JavaScript (maybe Google Analytics) interfering with the page.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Any other ideas? Why would it work for one site and not the other if they are almost mirrors of each other?